# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'status' for Recording

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

when i write in cmd "rake db:seed", then i got this error:

> rake aborted!
>
> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'status' for Recording.
>   G:/program/Rails/weather/db/seeds.rb:2:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:seed
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

**That is my "seeds.rb" code**

```
`l = Location.create(name: "New York City")
 l.recordings.create(temp: 32, status: "cloudy")
 l.recordings.create(temp: 34, status: "rainy")
 l.recordings.create(temp: 30, status: "rainy")
 l.recordings.create(temp: 28, status: "cloudy")
 l.recordings.create(temp: 22, status: "sunny")`
```

Comment: You could be missing an attribute or a relationship. Show us your `Recording` and `Location` models and migrations.

Comment: Long shot, but were you using an enum to represent possible values for status by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `status` attribute in your migration for `Recording` model.

Follow these steps from terminal:

```
# add `status` column in `recordings` table
rails generate migration AddStatusToRecording status:string
rake db:migrate

# seed the data into the db
rake db:seed
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `UnknownAttributeError` because you don't have a column in your Recordings table. Have you generated the status column yet? If not, you can do `rails generate migration AddStatusToPRecordings status:string`. Then do a `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is came up if we missed field to insert in our database and used in code. that's the only condition to show this issue.**

create migration script

```
bin/rails generate migration addStatusToReceiptItems

class AddStatusToReceiptItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :receipt_items, :status, :boolean
  end
end
```

**Then ran the command**

```
rake db:migrate
```